# Remove class when an image is loaded

Tags: jquery, removeclass, loaded

I have an image element looking like this:

```
<img class="heroStr border" id="pictureId_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" src="images/no_img.png" title="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $row['imageUrl']; ?>" />
```

When the data-src has finished downloading the src are switched (the "no_img" src shows a temporary image until the real one has finished loading). It works perfectly with this code:

```
jQuery("#element img").load(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).data('src'));
});
```

What I want to do is **remove** the `border` class from the `img` when the image is loaded. I suppose I would just add `jQuery(this).removeClass('border');` to the function but it doesn't work.

What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks!

**— EDIT —**

Added a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qtdj/6/) you can use to try it out. What I'm trying to achieve now is to **remove the border class** when the **data-src attribute has been loaded**.

Comment: Do you have multiple images here or just a single image?

Comment: @PalashMondal I have like 30 images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that is an asynchronous call so you're trying to remove a class that actually does not exist yet. You can try to use `.done()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, that's what I thought too. So how do I use the `.done()` function in this case? I'm not that good with jQuery, is it something like this? 

`jQuery("#element img").attr('data-src').done(function(){ jQuery(this).removeClass('border'); });`

Comment: It could work..but , are you using `.load` `function` because you're making an `AJAX` request? If so, `.done()` will do the trick.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work... No, I'm retrieving images with a while loop using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

for remove `loading` class of loaded images

just add this code at the end of `<body>`

```
let pending_images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
pending_images.forEach((img) => {
  let isLoaded = img.complete && img.naturalHeight !== 0;
  if (isLoaded) {
    img.classList.remove("loading");
  } else {
    img.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
      img.classList.remove("loading");
    });
  }
});
```

**do not** put this code in `Domcontentloaded` or `$(document).ready()`